# Where oozie job logs are stored

Tags: oozie, hadoop2, oozie-coordinator

When I got a need to look for oozie job logs. I got the configuration having the following entry.

**${oozie.log.dir}/oozie.log**

I want to know,what ${oozie.log.dir} parameters resolves? Is this a path in Oozie server? If Yes, can we access it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Check `oozie-env.sh` for logs dir. It will be `OOZIE_HOME/logs` mostly

Comment: by default it configured to /var/log/oozie folder in local linux machine.